# How to define user-definable custom types at compile-time for a library using stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

After working on my Haskell project for a while I decided on using multiple executables with a single library with stack. The reason behind, is that I want to have multiple test executables so that each can showcase some uses for the  single library that I am writing. The problem occurred when I tried to define a type that could be potentially different for each executable.

To give you an idea of what I would like to accomplish:

I currently have a type synonim defined in my library:

```
type GameState = Int
```

The type `Int` woks for executable 1, however, for the compilation of the executable two, I want `MyOtherDataType` to take place of the `Int`:

```
type GameState = AnotherDataType
```

I tried setting the state type variable using a `#define`, with the help of the [CPP Language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-1.12.0/Language-Haskell-Extension.html%20%22CPP). This variable could be passed as a parameter at compile time for the library, but I couldn't make stack route a defined type variable in the executable definition to the library (Eg: `-DGAME_STATE_TYPE=Int`). This is the closest idea I have for a clean solution that wouldn't require rewriting a lot of my code.

I also tried changing the type definition to:

```
data GameStateType a = GameStateType a
```

but I soon learned that this would require me to rewrite a lot of type classes, type definitions, monad stacks, and enable extensions such as MultiParamTypeClasses. I don't think that is a path I want to go given the time constraint, however, I would like to hear it anyways should you consider this the only/better option.

Comment: Sounds like [backpack](http://plv.mpi-sws.org/backpack/backpack-paper.pdf) would be the ideal fit, but that's a pretty bleeding-edge feature still. Realistically speaking, parameterising `GameStateType` is the most sensible option, and certainly a safer one if you need to get it working quickly – this really shouldn't be too difficult, the compiler will guide you through all the refactoring. Extra type classes should _not_ be required, given that simple CPP switching seems to work.

Comment: I propose that you replace `GameState` by `a` everywhere in your API. But whether that will work depends a lot on how `GameState` appears in your library's API, and you haven't said anything about that. That makes it very difficult to evaluate whether a potential answer would fit your situation well.